# Sequelize.js: how to sort query results based on values in where in closure ?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I issue the next query:

```
        Users.findAll({
            where : {
                user_id: {
                    in : [ data.user_id, data.user_id_to_replace ]
                }
            }
        }).then(function(results){})
```

I would like the results would be sorted by the order I have in the where in closure, i.e. first come for data.user_id and only then data.user_id_to_replace. I know how to do this in javascript, but I'm looking if there is a param in Sequelize that does this job for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems there is no sequelize built-in solution to my problem. Then here is a method using underscore I used for sorting finally. Hope this will be helpful someone looking to solve the same issue:

```
_.sortBy(results, function(item) {
    return item.get('user_id') === data.user_id ? 0 : 1
})
```